# How to remove option from select if already exists in database for the user in .net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-core

I have a page where students supply their Olevel result. Currently, for example, a student can register Mathematics more than once with either the same grade or another grade

I've tried checking the database in the GET method where the students number and subject exists

```
ViewBag.ListofSubjects = new SelectList(_context.AdmSubjects, "SubjectId", "SubjectName");
ViewBag.ListofGrades = new SelectList(_context.AdmSubjectGrades, "GradeId", "Grade");
ViewBag.jambreg = regNo;
var stolevel = _context.StApplicationsOlevel.FirstOrDefault(i => i.JambregNo == regNo);
var stolevel = _context.StApplicationsOlevel.Include(x => x.JambregNo).Where(x => !x.JambregNo.Any()).ToLis‌​t();
return View(stolevel);
```

I need a result that will remove subject from the dropdown list if it has already been chosen by that student

Comment: Are you needing this to happen immediately client-side or just when the page loads from the server it shouldn't have the user's selected subjects then?

Comment: Yes @ChrisPratt I need it to happen immediately the page loads from the server

Comment: I may have not been clear. I mean like the user selects something and that option immediately disappears from the list, without involving the server again at all, or are you wanting the page to come from the server with user-selected items *already* removed, such that they are never even rendered in the first place.

Comment: @ChrisPratt If you're visiting the page at first, it will populate all the subjects but once you select a subject and you save, when you are coming back to that page, the previous subject that you selected will not load with the other options

Comment: do you have relationship table between student and subjects? In your example we cannot determine what subjects had been selected by that student.

Comment: Yes I have a relationship between subjects and students tables @Sherlock

Comment: I would suggest that you could show us all the relationships between your tables.(many-to-many?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Chris 's and my reply provide possible solution which works similarly：Get list of existing `SubjectNames` using your `StudentId` and the relationships between Student and Subject , then retrieve data without these names.

You do not show your relatonships between `Subject` and `Student`, assume that they are [many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many) relationships:

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public List<StudentSubject> StudentSubjects { get; set; }

}


public class Subject
{
    [Key]
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }

    public List<StudentSubject> StudentSubjects { get; set; }

    public int? SubjectGradeId { get; set; }
    public SubjectGrade SubjectGrade { get; set; }
}

public class StudentSubject
{
    public int? StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    public int? SubjectId { get; set; }
    public Subject Subject { get; set; }
}
```

dbcontext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {

        builder.Entity<StudentSubject>()
        .HasKey(pt => new { pt.SubjectId, pt.StudentId });

        builder.Entity<StudentSubject>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Student)
            .WithMany(p => p.StudentSubjects)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.StudentId);

        builder.Entity<StudentSubject>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Subject)
            .WithMany(t => t.StudentSubjects)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.SubjectId);
    }
```

You could retrieve data like

```
var studentId = 1; 
var existedNames = _context.StudentSubject.Where(s => s.StudentId == studentId).Select(s => s.Subject.SubjectName).ToList();
//You need to get list based on your own models

ViewBag.ListofSubjects = new SelectList(_context.AdmSubjects.Where(s=> !existedNames.Contains(s.SubjectName)), "SubjectId", "SubjectName");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It really helped and solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your question still isn't completely clear, but based on my understanding, you need to 1) get the list of subjects currently selected by the user and 2) remove those subjects from the list of all subjects you're storing in the `SelectList`.

I don't have your entities to work with, but I'm assuming you should have a class that acts as a join between user and subjects, since that's a pretty clear many to many.

```
var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
var selectedSubjectIds = await _context.UserSubjects.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).Select(x => x.SubjectId);
```

Then:

```
ViewBag.ListofSubjects = new SelectList(await _context.AdmSubjects.Where(x => !selectedSubjectIds.Contains(x.SubjectId).ToListAsync(), "SubjectId", "SubjectName");
```

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately, it does not work

Comment: `ViewBag.ListofSubjects = new SelectList(await _context.AdmSubjects.Where(x => !selectedSubjectIds.Contains(x.SubjectId).ToListAsync(), "SubjectId", "SubjectName");` @Chris Pratt

Comment: I'm not using identity

Comment: Identity has nothing to do with this. However, you're authenticating, there will be a ClaimsPrincipal (User), and there should be a user id claim. The point is that you need to use the user id to get subjects that user has selected, and then exclude that list of subjects from your query. Saying it doesn't "work" is not helpful to you or me. I'm flying blind here because you've left critical info out of your question. Take the *spirit* of the answer, and modify it for your particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As the relation between student and subject is many to many, you may need another table called SubjectSelected with columns StudentId, SubjectId where subjectSelected is a reference to Subject table and student is reference to Student table. This way you can simply retrieve subjects which are not in SubjectSelected table in your dropdownlist.
Something like below.

```
ViewBag.ListofSubjects = new SelectList(_context.AdmSubjects.Where(s => 
                         !s.SubjectSelected.Any());
```

After the subject is selected, you will have to make sure row is inserted to SubjectSelected table.